# Manter Dados Iguais

Tags: android

Estou fazendo um *Chat* em Android.

Estou usando Servlet (com JSON) + Oracle + Android.

Quando eu adicionar um contato, por exemplo, eu salvo esse contato no banco de dados Oracle, via Servlet.

Mas, na hora de exibir os contatos em um `ListView`, se eu buscar esses dados via JSON do servidor, pode ser que, o usuario não tenha internet e com isso, ele não conseguiria ver os contatos dele.

Qual seria a melhor solução pra isso?

Criar um banco local e criar um serviço que deixa os dois bancos iguais?

Aceito sugestões.

Comment: Você pode baixar o seu JSON e guardar num arquivo mesmo, tem alguns aplicativos que fazem isso, como por exemplo o Nubank.. Mas tem um detalhe... Vai ser possível adicionar um contato sem internet?

Comment: Acho que sim, se não ficaria muito limitado.

Comment: acho q a solução mais rápida seria o uso de um banco local (SQLite), mas se vc tiver q fazer muitos registros e o uso dos dois bancos ficar muito trabalhoso acho melhor achar uma saída mais viável

Comment: @Luhhh, editei minha resposta adicionando uma outra implementação. Utilizo ambas as formas em sistemas diferentes aqui na empresa onde eu trabalho.

Answer (score 8):

Bom, como é uma pergunta baseada em opiniões, vou expor a minha.

Primeiro de tudo eu faria um banco local (SQLite).

Esse banco seria um espelho do meu banco remoto.

Para garantir a maior segurança dos dados e sincronização, eu criaria um serviço em background toda vez que o aplicativo estiver aberto.

Que que o meu serviço faria?

1. Obter uma lista com os contatos locais (SQLite).
2. Enviar essa lista para um webservice.
3. Mediante recebimento da lista, ter um algoritmo que faça uma varredura de todos os contatos recebidos comparando-os com os contatos já salvos.
4. Se houver diferença de contatos, fazer o necessário para atualizar ambos os lados.
5. Neste caso, posso ter duas situações: O banco local estar maior que o remoto (o que me obriga a fazer uma atualização do remoto). Ou o banco remoto estar maior que o local. (o que me obriga a fazer uma atualização do local).

Em qualquer um desses casos você vai fazer a mesma coisa: Sincronizar os bancos.

Como você mencionou que está trabalhando com servlets, você pode utilizar o `removeAll` para comparar duas listas (a lista do banco local e do banco remoto).

```
Collection listaRemota = new ArrayList() {{
    add("maca");
    add("laranja");
}};

Collection listaLocal = new ArrayList() {{
    add("maca");
    add("laranja");
    add("coco");
    add("morango");
}};

// Remover os elementos 
listaLocal.removeAll(listaRemota);

// Exibir resultado
System.out.println("Resultado: " + listaLocal);

Resultado: ["coco", "morango", "laranja"]
```

Lembrando que, como o seu caso é uma comparação (complexa ou não) de objetos. Você precisará definir uma regra de comparação (sobrecarga do método `equals()`) para poder utilizar tal mecanismo.

**Outro exemplo de implementação**

Você também pode empilhar todas as ações em cima de qualquer contato. Assim você vai ter sempre a maior massa de dados no seu banco local (SQLite) e garante a sincronização toda vez que o dispositivo mobile apresentar conectividade com a internet.

Você pode criar uma tabela do tipo:

```
CREATE TABLE sincronizacao (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ENTIDADE varchar(20), ACAO varchar(1), VALOR varchar(500), SINCRONIZADO INTEGER, DATA_SINCRONIZAR INTEGER);
```

Você pode fazer um método genérico em cada ação tomada em cima de um contato (`INSERT`,`UPDATE`,`DELETE`) que vai gravar exatamente o "estado" - ou valor - do contato:

```
insert into sincronizacao (entidade, acao, valor, sincronizado, data_sincronizar) values ('CONTATO', 'I', '{  "telefones": [    "(21) 91111-2222",    "(21) 92477-1515"  ],  "nome": "Stack Overflow PT",  "null": null,  "endereco": "Brasil",  "object": {    "a": "b",    "c": "d",    "e": "f"  },  "outra_propriedade": "Olá, mundo!"}', 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

O valor acima é um JSON, ou seja, você pode fazer a serialização e deserialização em qualquer dos "lados":

```
{
  "telefones": [
    "(21) 91111-2222",
    "(21) 92477-1515"
  ],
  "nome": "Stack Overflow PT",
  "null": null,
  "endereco": "Brasil",
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "outra_propriedade": "Olá, mundo!"
}
```

Daí eu faço uma alteração em alguma propriedade desse mesmo contato e faço outro registro na minha tabela:

```
insert into sincronizacao (entidade, acao, valor, sincronizado, data_sincronizar) values ('CONTATO', 'U', '{  "telefones": [    "(21) 91111-2222",    "(21) 92477-1515"  ],  "nome": "Stack Overflow PT",  "null": null,  "endereco": "Brasil",  "object": {    "a": "b",    "c": "d",    "e": "f"  },  "outra_propriedade": "Olá, mundo! Essa propriedade foi alterada."}', 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

`VALOR` na visão "familiar":

```
{
  "telefones": [
    "(21) 91111-2222",
    "(21) 92477-1515"
  ],
  "nome": "Stack Overflow PT",
  "null": null,
  "endereco": "Brasil",
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "outra_propriedade": "Olá, mundo! Essa propriedade foi alterada."
}
```

Você também pode criar uma [trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) que faça isso.

De qualquer forma no fim das contas você vai fazer a mesma coisa:

Obter uma lista com as sincronizações não realizadas:

```
select * from sincronizacao where sincronizado = 0;
```

Fazer o envio de uma lista de objetos (depois de deserializá-los) para um webservice. No webservice, segue o mesmo fluxo de tratamento na ordem crescente da `data_sincronizar`.

No caso acima, repare que primeiro eu fiz uma ação "I" (`insert`) e depois fiz outra ação "U" (`update`). No tratamento da lista do lado do webservice, vou executar as ações de acordo com a ordem que elas foram "criadas". Então no meu servidor remoto, faria primeiro um `insert` do objeto deserializado. E logo depois faria um `update`.

Retornando um "OK" do webservice, você "varre" a mesma lista enviada e faz um update da sua coluna de controle `sincronizado`:

```
update sincronizacao set sincronizado = 1 where id in (string_delimitada_por_virgula_com_cada_id_atualizado_no_ws);
```

E pronto!

Dessa forma você também garante sempre a atualização local (que é mais importante no seu caso) e garante também a sincronização e segurança desses dados guardando as informações num servidor remoto, visto que, para utilização do chat, é necessário conexão com a internet.

Answer (score 2):

Dê prioridade em salvar os dados localmente ao invés de salvá‐los num servidor externo.

Os motivos estão na própria pergunta. Se não houver conexão com a internet, não conseguirá nem mesmo adicionar um novo contato ou simples ações como editar um contato existente, excluir, etc.

Sugiro que salve localmente e crie opções para “exportar” para um meio externo, o qual que pode ser um arquivo txt (csv), envio por bluetooth, banco de dados, etc.

Isso é, inclusive, o que todos os apps do tipo fazem.

Acredito que não há necessidade em mostrar códigos pois a dúvida parece ser apenas conceitual.